Visual Studio Build Event in referenced project
I have two projects: Project B is referenced by root project A. Project B have some text files in the Files subfolder I want to copy to the output folder bin/debug.
I setup the post build event in Project B as
xcopy /Y "$(ProjectDir)Files\*.txt" $(TargetDir)
However these files are not copied to the bin/debug folder of Project A when I build Project A
Project B
 |
 |-Files
     |
     |-FileA.txt
     |-FileB.txt

What is the correct macros to use to indicate the root project being built instead of $(TargetDir)?
One work around is to market FileA.txt and FileB.txt as Copy Always so they are copied to ProjectA/bin/debug/Files, and in Project A config, I do xcopy to copy them to the bin/debug folder and delete the Files bin/debug/subfolder, but I feel it is the wrong method as Project B should be responsible for all these stuffs. Thanks

The issue might be due to $(ProjectDir)Files*.txt being incorrect, as $(ProjectDir)Files*.txt refers to all .txt files in the Project A directory.
Try replacing $(ProjectDir)Files*.txt with the direct path of Project B.
If you want to use a macro instead of a direct path, you need to define a new macro in the project file, such as the .csproj file, using XML.
For example:
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectBDir>$(SolutionDir)ProjectB</ProjectBDir>    <!-- You need to write the project B path in this line. -->
</PropertyGroup>

Then use the Post-build event command line:
xcopy /Y "$(ProjectBDir)*.txt" "$(TargetDir)"

More about define a macro can refer to MS document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022

@ZhengningZhang I had a typo, the post-build event was actually setup in Project B.
